# Show that $f(A ∩ f ^{−1} (B)) = f(A) ∩ B$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that $f(A ∩ f^{-1}(B)) = f(A) ∩ B$.

$f^{-1}$ is a inverse image. Sorry, if it wasn't clear enough. And $∩$ stands for intersection.

I'm pretty sure that I need to to use definition of inverse image, then defition of ∩ and in the end definition of image. But I don't know how to properly write it.

I hope you can help me.
If something is unintelligible or grammatically uncorrect, I'm sorry. English isn't my first language.

Comment: Well start by writing down the definitions.

Comment: @Iribell HINT: say that inverse of $f(B)$ is equal to $C$ where $C$ is a set.After that , show that the both sides are the subsets of each others

Answer (score 3):

It’s just a matter of element-chasing to show that each side of the equation is a subset of the other. I’ll do half of it.

Suppose that $x\in f[A]\cap B$; then there is an $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=x\in B$. Since $f(a)\in B$, we know that $a\in f^{-1}[B]$, so $a\in A\cap f^{-1}[B]$, and therefore $x=f(a)\in f\big[A\cap f^{-1}[B]\big]$. This shows that

$$f[A]\cap B\subseteq f\big[A\cap f^{-1}[B]\big]\,.$$

Now suppose that $x\in f\big[A\cap f^{-1}[B]\big]$; then there is an $a\in A\cap f^{-1}[B]$ such that ... what? And how can you use this $a$ to show that $x\in f[A]\cap B$?

Answer (score 1):

Well first $f(A\cap B)\subset f(A)\cap f(B)$ (I'll let you prove this one), and $f(f^{-1}(A))=A$ (trivial), so we already have the inclusion. Now take $y\in f(A)\cap B$, since this is a subset of $f(A)$ there exists an element $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=y$, but since $y\in B$, $x\in f^{-1}(B)$ so $x\in A\cap f^{-1}(B)$ and $y\in f(A\cap f^{-1}(B))$, therefore by double inclusion we have $f(A\cap f^{-1}(B))=f(A)\cap B$

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation helped me a lot.